# Forward one email address to multiple email addresses on Cloudflare

Tags: email, cloudflare, mx-record

I have a domain `mydomain.com` registered on Cloudflare and I need to forward one email address `from@mydomain.com` to multiple email addresses (let's say `one@example.com` and `two@example.com`).
I've looked for a way to do it on Cloudflare, but I couldn't find any straightforward method, even though it seems to be a simple operation with other email providers.

I don't want to change my email provider because I have everything set up in Cloudflare already. I am currently able to forward emails to a single email address using the "Email Routing" panel, but I need to forward them to multiple email addresses.

I've looked into the "Email Workers" beta feature on Cloudflare, but I'm not sure if it can be used to achieve this setup.

Does anyone know if there's a workaround or a way to do this on Cloudflare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with email workers on cloudflare.

You'll need to  add each email address as a destination email and verify it (you'll get sent a link to click on). Once that is done create an email worker:

```
export default {
  async email(message, env, ctx) {
    await message.forward("example1@gmail.com");
    await message.forward("example2@gmail.com");
  }
}
```

And connect that worker to your email route.